# How to create a custom @jsonDeserializer class in java

Tags: java, json, rest

I have a java class. Which is related to many other java classes.
and I want to deserialize this class. Please help me to deserialize the class.
  My class is like this..

@Entity
@Table(name = "A", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "name" }))
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@_refid")
@JsonDeserialize(using=ADeSerializer.class)
public class A {

```
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
private String description;
```

//

```
@ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE},fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
        name="B",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="Aname")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="Bname", unique=true)}
    )
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private Set<C> cs;

@ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.MERGE},fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
        name="D",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="Aname"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="Ename")
    )
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private Set<E> Es;

@Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN})
@ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.MERGE},fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
        name="F",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="Aname"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="Fname")
    )
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private Set<F> Fs;



// Getters and setters
```

}

Saying clearly...

```
 Class A {
        Object of Class B;
        Object of Class C {
                  Set<ClassB> bs;
               Objects of Class C;
               Object of Class A
          }
       other local variables;

      Objects of Class D{
             set<ClassB> ds;
        }
```

//Getters and setters

}

My rest service is

@RequestMapping(value="/saveA", method=RequestMethod.POST )
    public  @ResponseBody MIResponse saveA(@RequestBody A a) throws Exception{

```
    return null;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Class for @JsonDeserializer in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438684/custom-class-for-jsondeserializer-in-java)